# How can I auto install programmatically app without start Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Tags: android

In fact, I want to be noticed when the program is downloaded without the user having to install their own apps **(Install without show permissions activity)**.
Now I use the following code, and I want to change this code to answer my question.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

The **following image** is displayed after downloading the app from my server and **i dont want to show**

[image: this iamge]

Comment: It is not possible at all.

Comment: I see the inside of a program